# Is there a replacement for Python namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

The official documentation for the Python [collections module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) states that namedtuple, deque, ChainMap, Counter, OrderedDict, defaultdict, UserDict, UserList, and UserString were deprecated since Python 3.3 and will be removed in Python 3.9:

> Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.9: Moved Collections Abstract Base Classes to the collections.abc module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible in this module through Python 3.8.

I read the documentation for the replacement module: [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). After reading, it's not clear to me that there is a replacement for namedtuple. What is the recommended replacement for collections.namedtuple starting with Python 3.9?

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the sentence in the first part of your post. Only ABC has been deprecated and moved to `collections.abc`. The other containers (namedtuple, deque, ChainMap, Counter, OrderedDict, defaultdict, UserDict, UserList, and UserString) are not being deprecated.

Comment: @CoryKramer is of course right. But if it was the case, Dataclasses seems to be the next best choice.  
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: Ah yes, @CodyKramer is correct. I misunderstood what was being deprecated. Sorry for any confusion that I caused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the documentation for Python ver. 3.8.2 at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple and it is definitely not deprecated. Some features appear to have changed though:

> Changed in version 3.6: The verbose and rename parameters became keyword-only arguments.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: Added the module parameter.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Removed the verbose parameter and the _source attribute.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Added the defaults parameter and the _field_defaults attribute.

As @CoryKramer pointed out in his comment, the depreciation is only for the ABC bit.

Answer (score 3):

There are some variations. Class *typing*.**NamedTuple** should be used for subclasses in place of *collections*.**namedtuple**()

Some changes have happened:

> Changed in version 3.6: Added support for [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526) variable annotation
> syntax.
>
> Changed in version 3.6.1: Added support for default values, methods,
> and docstrings.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: The `_field_types` and `__annotations__`
> attributes are now regular dictionaries instead of instances of
> `OrderedDict`.
>
> Changed in version 3.9: Removed the `_field_types` attribute in favor of
> the more standard `__annotations__` attribute which has the same
> information.